# Isn't there a tense inconsistency in the following context?

Tags: grammar

In the movie *Knives Out* (2019), Detective Benoit Blanc (Daniel Craig) says,

> The body is discovered early the next morning. The police, the medical
> examiner, the family, everyone **swarmed in**, and there is no
> possible way you can get to Marta's medical bag to retrieve the vials.

Isn't there a tense inconsistency here? Maybe I'm just being pedantic, but I think "swarmed in" is not correct here, given that the story is described in present tense.

Comment: ............................. Yes.

Comment: If you add in what the full context is -- who the detective is talking to, when this event happened, etc., then someone might be able to explain the tense inconsistency